# Will Ubuntu 14.04 release security updates for openssl 1.0.1 even after 31st December 2016 or will they move to openssl 1.0.2

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, security, openssl

The 1.0.1 version is currently only receiving security bug fixes and all support will be discontinued for this version on 31st December 2016. 
<[Link](https://www.openssl.org/source/)> as stated in their website.

OpenSSL is installed from the main repository of Ubuntu by default during installation.

As ubuntu 14.04 has long term support. So, should I expect upgraded version of OpenSSL or should we have to upgrade it by ourselves.

Comment: Good question, 16.04 runs on 10.0.2 but i cant tell you anything about 14.04 so maybe heres a canonical answer needed.

Comment: The Security team will most likely be continuing to backport critical fixes for OpenSSL to older versions for the lifespan of Trusty.  The Security team is usually *very* good at this.

Comment: Launchpad Bug #1474541 says: debian/patches/0001-Support-openssl-1.0.2b-and-above.patch: handle the case where we can't get the issuer certificate, which typically happens after 1.0.2b; but it appears that 1.0.1f includes that check too, which fails in sbsigntool.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question appears to be that security updates will be released (backported) as needed through the [duration of Trusty LTS support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).  There are currently no plans to release  openssl 1.0.2 for Trusty. According to the posts [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1596693) only security patches will be released for 1.01 after 2016-12-31. It seems the latest source available is 1.0.1e available [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/)

***Why?***

Marc Deslauriers (Ubuntu Security Engineer) states: 
"Ubuntu doesn't typically update to newer software versions. Like most other Linux distros, we backport security patches to the versions of software we ship, whether or not there is still upstream support for it."

So the commitment to security is there.

If you feel the need to upgrade regardless you can obtain the source [on this page](https://www.openssl.org/source/) and compile it yourself. Installation instructions are included in the archive but it's pretty straight forward even if you've never compiled code before.

Note that I'm not recommending this as a course of action, I'm simply attempting to be thorough in covering the possibilities.

```
  $ ./config
  $ make
  $ make test
  $ make install
```

Sources:

https://www.openssl.org/source/

Installation instructions included in https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz

As an alternative you could upgrade to xenial (16.04) which has version [1.0.2g](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openssl) already available or as Seth Arnold (Member Ubuntu Security Team) states [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1596693)

"16.04 LTS's openssl package is based on a 1.0.2g starting point. If running 16.04 LTS is not an option then perhaps the [backportpackage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=backportpackage&searchon=contents) command from the [ubuntu-dev-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-dev-tools) package could help you."

Comment: upgrading openssl has lot of issues. First ruby points to old version of openssl which is provided by ubuntu its self and same case goes with nginx. So, if possible give me proper solution for upgrade. Solution you have given everyone knows. But why ubuntu is not releasing latest version of openssl as it is used as core software.

Comment: @fkraiem Updated answer.

Comment: The fact that fixes will be backported, but only fixes, is confirmed by my contacts on the Security team.  That said, they are not updating Trusty to a later OpenSSL version due to the extreme level of explosions that will happen with packages that are not updated for those 'newer' OpenSSL versions in that release

Comment: So, LTS really means "if it's not too much work"?  I've been expecting to ride 14.04 until 18.04 comes out (in hopes that KDE will improve again), but now it looks like that's a bad idea...

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm not sure I understand your position here. Security patches are still being offered for 1.01 [currently at 1.01f](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssl) Why so upset?

Comment: Wasn't the original question about OpenSSL dropping *all* support for 1.01 (as of two months ago)?

Comment: A quick check of the edit history shows the original question was "Will Ubuntu 14.04 release security updates for openssl 1.0.1 or will they move to openssl 1.0.2" be that as it may, 1.1.0e source was made available 2017-Feb-16 12:03:39 See [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/)

Answer (score 0):

This [Ubuntu search page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssl) gives no indication that Canonical is offering a newer version of openssl for 14.04 LTS.  Given the impending loss of all support for openssl 1.0.1, one would hope someone with package authority will backport 1.0.2 from 16.04, but that apparently has not yet occurred (as of December 22, 2016).

Comment: Nor will it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/863477/will-ubuntu-14-04-release-security-updates-for-openssl-1-0-1-even-after-31st-dec/863556#comment1335563_863556